# SSIS merge join data from 2 rows from left into one row from right

Tags: merge, ssis

This is the scenario i have. My right side of the flow returns the main record lets say with following data:

```
Id    Category    SubCategory
--    --------    -----------
1     null        null
```

The left flow reads a json array with the following data:

```
Id   ParentId    Type          Value
--   --------    --------      -----------
1    1           Category      A
2    1           SubCategory   B
```

The outcome i want to get is (by conditionally putting each array record into a specific field based on its type):

```
Id    Category    SubCategory
--    --------    -----------
1     A           B
```

But no matter whether i use inner, left or full outer in the merge join, i always get 2 records like this:

```
Id    Category    SubCategory
--    --------    -----------
1     null        B
1     A           null
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: A join requires join columns. Please specify your join columns. This looks more like a job for Pivot

Comment: the join colum is ID in the main table, and ParentID in the array table. the join works ok but the output gives me duplicate rows one row with category populated, other with subcategory populated

Comment: There are two records with `ParentId=1` in one table and one matching record in the other so the result = 2 x 1 records = 2 records. It looks like you just need to do an pivot on your second table, and your first table appears to be irrelevant.

Comment: JSON source -> Pivot and depending on business requirements, a Lookup Transformation against the "Right" table is how I'd likely structure this